# Java, calling static method on elements given from HashMap, how to?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
class Depot
{
}

class Depot1 extends Depot
{
    public static void callMe() { }
}

class Depot2 extends Depot
{
    public static void callMe() { }
}

class Depot3 extends Depot
{
    public static void callMe() { }
}

class Depot4 extends Depot
{
    public static void callMe() { }
}

HashMap<Integer, Depot> depots;

depots.put("1", new Depot1());
depots.put("3", new Depot3());
```

and now:

```
depots.get("1").callMe()
```

invalid! No `callMe()` in `Depot`. How to dodge it?

Comment: Your method names are inconsistent. What is the relation between `getStarterDirection` and `callme`?

Comment: Where are you trying to define `getStarterDirection`? I don't see it anywhere in your definitions. Your base `Depot` class doesn't contain any methods, so how do you expect to call anything on it?

Comment: sorry for all, I fixed that.

Comment: @JohnSmith Polymorphism does not apply to static methods. So each type you call `callMe` you will actually call the static method from Depot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two major problems:

- `depots.get("1")` has type `Depot`, and `Depot` doesn't declare a `callMe` method.
- Even if `Depot` did declare a `callMe` method, static methods aren't virtual (and therefore not overrideable), because they aren't called on *instances*, but rather on *classes*. (That's what "static" means in Java.) So something like `depots.get("1").callMe()` would call `Depot.callMe`, not `Depot1.callMe`. (It's arguably a mistake in Java that it even lets you write `depots.get("1").callMe()` instead of `Depot1.callMe()` when `callMe` is a static method.)

To fix this:

- change `Depot` to declare an abstract, non-static, `callMe` method.
- remove the `static` keyword in its subclasses, so they override that method.

Comment: I was affraid so, its not the first time I run into this static thing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misunderstanding the concept of static methods. These methods are associated with a class, not with an object. Because of this it makes no sense to try to override them.

You might need to explain why you are making `callMe` static as there's likely to be a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: those "callMe" return with static data. I mean, it was just like to get a final int, or a constant, or something like that. Its result depends on the class itself, not on the instance(s) of it. Its like if Math.max wasnt static. Whats the point in creating new Math().max ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is something that need polymorphism..

You need and interface that contains a **callMe** method

```
public interface Depot {
    void callMe();
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class Depot1 implements Depot{

    @Override
    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("Depot1!");
    }

}

public class Depot2 implements Depot{

    @Override
    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("Depot2!");
    }

}
```

and now, in your main class you can invoke callMe from HashMap, without using static methods..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<Integer, Depot> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(1, new Depot1());
            map.put(2, new Depot2());

            map.get(1).callMe();    // Depot1!
            map.get(2).callMe();    // Depot2!
        }

    }
```